# How to retrieve an Id from the console.log(ui)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jquery where I did a console.log(ui).
When I inspected my browser I got an object in the attached image

```
        stop: function (event, ui) {
            
            console.log(ui);
          
        }
```

I want to be able to retrieve that number after div# highlighted
in yellow in the image. How can I retrieve just that number and
pass to a javascript method?[image]

Comment: try `console.log(ui.helper[0])` and see what you get in the results

Comment: This is what I got <div class="draggable position-absolute ui-draggable obstacle" id="9"
style="left: 441.25px; top: 179.25px;"> from using the line of code you sent me. I need to extract the Id though

Answer (score 2):

Ok here you go. If you get html from `console.log(ui.helper[0])` you can retrieve easily.

Example:

```js
var str = '<div class="draggable position-absolute ui-draggable obstacle" id="9" style="left: 441.25px; top: 179.25px;">'; // get from ui.helper[0]
var raw = $(str);
var result = raw.attr("id");
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```